# Splitting Integers that are inside a List in Python

Tags: python

How would I take a list of integers like this:

```
[12,23,32]
```

and get it to have the output when printed of:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2]
```

For those who choose to not help because of "code-writing", here you go:

```
sequence = [12, 23, 32]

print([int(i) for i in sequence])
```

Comment: I have no clue how to do it because I an new to python. And yes it has been answered in many different ways but not splitting multiple integers up already in a list.

Comment: You can use an existing solution and do it for each item of the list. Convert the integers to strings, contatenate them, then build a new list of each char converted to an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `split` function:

```py
a = [12, 23, 32]


def split(l):
    final_list = []
    for item in l:
        for elem in list(str(item)):
            final_list.append(int(elem))

    return final_list


print(split(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import itertools
a = [12, 23, 32]
b = [int(z) for z in list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([list(str(x)) for x in a]))]
print(b)
```